How to have multiple python multi-process save to a variable
Im working on doing some image processing on a very large image 25 088 pixels by 36 864 pixels big. since the image is very large i do the image processing by 256x256 pixel 'tiles'. I noticed that on my windows task manager neither my CPU,RAM,GPU, or SSD reaches 50% utilization when running my function. This lead me to believe that there is performance i can squeeze out somehow.
def processImage(self, img, tileSize = 256, numberOfThreads = 8): # a function within a class

    height, width, depth = img.shape
    print(height,width,depth,img.dtype)

    #create a duplicate but empty matrix same as the img
    processedImage = np.zeros((height,width,3), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    #calculate left and top offsets
    leftExcessPixels = int((width%tileSize)/2)
    topExcessPixels =  int((height%tileSize)/2)
    
    #calculate the number of tiles columns(X) and row(Y)
    XNumberOfTiles =   int(width/tileSize)
    YNumberOfTiles =   int(height/tileSize)
    
    #
    for y in range(YNumberOfTiles):
        for x in range(XNumberOfTiles):
            XStart = (leftExcessPixels + (tileSize * x))
            YStart = (topExcessPixels + (tileSize * y))
            XEnd = XStart + tileSize
            YEnd = YStart + tileSize
            croppedImage = img[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd]
            
            print('Y: ' + str(y) + ' X: ' + str(x),end="  ")
            #process the cropped images and store it on the same location on the empty image
            processedImage[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd] = self.doSomeImageProcessing(croppedImage) 

Multi-threading seems to be the solution where i parallelize the processing of 'tiles'. since processing of the tiles are independent to each other, there should be no problem working on multiple tiles at the same time. What im not sure on how to do though is that the resulting matrix from  self.doSomeImageProcessing(croppedImage) should be placed back to the same coordinates but on a different variable named processedImage. Im worried that since there are multiple threads and all of them are trying to write to the processedImage image variable python might not like that so much, any ideas on how to approach it?
EDIT::
As @tijko mentioned multithreading is not the answer, but multiprocess. Here is a sample standalone code for testing
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array
from time import monotonic

import numpy as np

class myClass():
    def doSomeImageProcessing(self,npRGBImage):
        #Dummy image processing, just set all values to 255 or make the image white
        print('I have been called')
        a = npRGBImage
        for i in range(255):
            a[:] = i+1
        return a


    def processImage(self,tileSize = 256):

        #create a large dummy image
        img = np.zeros((25088,36864,3), dtype=np.uint8)

        height, width, depth = img.shape
        print(height,width,depth,img.dtype)

        processedImage = np.zeros((height,width,depth), dtype=np.uint8)


        leftExcessPixels = int((width%tileSize)/2)
        topExcessPixels =  int((height%tileSize)/2)

        XNumberOfTiles =   int(width/tileSize)
        YNumberOfTiles =   int(height/tileSize)


        for y in range(YNumberOfTiles):
            for x in range(XNumberOfTiles):
                XStart = (leftExcessPixels + (tileSize * x))
                YStart = (topExcessPixels + (tileSize * y))
                XEnd = XStart + tileSize
                YEnd = YStart + tileSize
                croppedImage = img[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd]
                
                print('Y: ' + str(y) + ' X: ' + str(x),end="  ")

                #Recreate the full image using the processed tiles

                #Original Approach
                #Run time 61.375 seconds
                processedImage[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd] = self.doSomeImageProcessing(croppedImage)



        #check if all indexes were set to 255
        mean = np.mean(processedImage)
        if  mean == 255:
            print('Image Processing successful: ', mean)
        else:
            print('Image Processing failed: ', mean)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    x=myClass()

    start_time = monotonic()
    x.processImage()
    print(f"Run time {monotonic() - start_time} seconds")

Output:
Image Processing successful:  255.0
Run time 61.360000000015134 seconds


The solution you are looking for is not multi-threading or asynchronous process, since that would just alternate between running one thread or the other, due to Python's GIL. However, multi-processing would allow you to launch an additional process that could make use of other core to increase performance in this case. You're right to worry about passing data and synchronisation, but it's best to start with a few simple examples and the documentation for multiprocessing, it can be done with fairly basic datatypes and functions.

Running the image data processing with a multi-threaded function in Python won't yield any more of an improvement with regards to overall performance.  This is due to the GIL or Global Interpreter Lock, which prevents the underlying interpreter from running more than one system thread at any given time.
What you can use to improve processing performance is to use the multiprocessing module, as @Grismar as already made mention of.
Without having the actual data to run tests on it's difficult to give you a working solution.  That said, from what I see in your code here you can do something along the lines of:
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array
import time

def processImage(self, img, tileSize = 256, numberOfThreads = 8): # a function within a class

    height, width, depth = img.shape
    print(height,width,depth,img.dtype)

    #create a duplicate but empty matrix same as the img
    processedImage = np.zeros((height,width,3), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    #calculate left and top offsets
    leftExcessPixels = int((width%tileSize)/2)
    topExcessPixels =  int((height%tileSize)/2)
    
    #calculate the number of tiles columns(X) and row(Y)
    XNumberOfTiles =   int(width/tileSize)
    YNumberOfTiles =   int(height/tileSize)
    
    #
    for y in range(YNumberOfTiles):
        for x in range(XNumberOfTiles):
            XStart = (leftExcessPixels + (tileSize * x))
            YStart = (topExcessPixels + (tileSize * y))
            XEnd = XStart + tileSize
            YEnd = YStart + tileSize
            croppedImage = img[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd]
            
            print('Y: ' + str(y) + ' X: ' + str(x),end="  ")
            #process the cropped images and store it on the same location on the empty image
            # XXX use a Shared Memory Data Structure
            image_array = Array('i', processedImage[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd])
            process = Process(target=self.doSomeImageProcessing, args=(image_array,))
            process.start()
            process.join()

Of course we can't tell how much of this will need to be adjusted without having the actual sample data to test but in general this should get you a good performance boost on the image processing time.
The important aspect that I would think you'll need to account for is having some shared state between these processes.  In the event you end up going this route there is shared memory maps which will allow you to access data across processes.
Again though you will need to provide a short self contained correct example

Hello than you for the answer, i added a sample code to play with. Also in your code image_array throws a type error TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. Also  the function doSomeImageProcessing has a return value how do i  access that so that i can save it in the processedImage variable?

@Jakequin "Also in your code image_array throws a type error."  I mentioned in my post that without any sample data (the images you're using) there's no way for people answering to create a "working example".  The link to sscce explains exactly what I am meaning.

The sscce needs a sign in , so i was not able to view it. I have edited the question to have a standalone example, hopefully that helps :)

Seems like the sscce page died, here's an archive link: https://archive.is/jhHHS

@JensV duly noted and I checked it out there is only a http version of the site.

Maybe with a spark job.
Set up a multi core cluster using docker or AWS EMR and submit the tile processor jobs as spark submit steps

When working with these particularly large images, I tent to using the pattern where I create a multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory as a buffer for the numpy array, and then re-open the same array in the child process so that the array is not duplicated in memory unnecessarily, and you also don't pay the performance penalty of transferring array data to and from the worker process. I have taken a somewhat literal approach to modifying your code to use this approach, but you could cut the usage in half by modifying the source image in-place rather than saving modifications to a new image.
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np



class myClass():

    def worker(self):
        src_img = np.ndarray(self.img_shape, self.img_dtype, self.src_shm.buf)  # re-create array using shared buffer in child process
        dst_img = np.ndarray(self.img_shape, self.img_dtype, self.dst_shm.buf)
        for task in iter(self.work_q.get, None):  # consume tiles until None (used as a stop flag)
            YStart, YEnd, XStart, XEnd = task
            dst_img[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd] = self.doSomeImageProcessing(src_img[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd])

        self.src_shm.close()  # close child-worker process local version of the shared memory
        self.dst_shm.close()

    def doSomeImageProcessing(self,npRGBImage):
        #Dummy image processing, just set all values to 255 or make the image white
        # print('I have been called')
        a = npRGBImage
        for i in range(255):
            a[:] = i+1
        return a


    def processImage(self,tileSize = 256):

        #create a less large dummy image (my poor laptop can't allocate 4+ GB to 2 shared memory files)
        img = np.zeros((5120,3840,3), dtype=np.uint8)

        height, width, depth = img.shape
        print(height,width,depth,img.dtype)

        leftExcessPixels = int((width%tileSize)/2)
        topExcessPixels =  int((height%tileSize)/2)

        XNumberOfTiles =   int(width/tileSize)
        YNumberOfTiles =   int(height/tileSize)

        self.img_shape = img.shape  # basically using self to send args to Process target function b/c I'm lazy.
        self.img_dtype = img.dtype

        img_bytes = img.shape[0]*img.shape[1]*img.shape[2]*img.dtype.itemsize  # calc number of bytes in img
        self.src_shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=img_bytes)
        src_img = np.ndarray(img.shape, img.dtype, self.src_shm.buf) #create array from shared buffer
        src_img[:] = img[:]  # copy img data to shared image array

        self.dst_shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=img_bytes)
        dst_img = np.ndarray(img.shape, img.dtype, self.dst_shm.buf)
        dst_img.flat[:] = 0  # don't technically need to zero. Fresh mem buffer should start at zero.

        self.work_q = Queue()  # to send jobs to worker processes

        pool = [Process(target=self.worker) for _ in range(cpu_count())]  # entire myClass object must be picklable in order to use a method as the target function. Otherwise make a separate (static) function outside your class

        for worker in pool:
            worker.start()

        for y in range(YNumberOfTiles):
            for x in range(XNumberOfTiles):
                XStart = (leftExcessPixels + (tileSize * x))
                YStart = (topExcessPixels + (tileSize * y))
                XEnd = XStart + tileSize
                YEnd = YStart + tileSize

                self.work_q.put((YStart, YEnd, XStart, XEnd),)  # feed tiles to the worker pool

        for worker in pool:
            self.work_q.put(None)  # send stop command to each worker

        for worker in pool:
            worker.join()  # wait for all workers to be done

        #check if all indexes were set to 255
        mean = np.mean(dst_img)
        if  mean == 255:
            print('Image Processing successful: ', mean)
        else:
            print('Image Processing failed: ', mean)

        #shm cleanup
        self.src_shm.close()  # don't try to access src_img after this (segfaults)
        self.src_shm.unlink()

        self.dst_shm.close()
        self.dst_shm.unlink()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    x=myClass()

    start_time = perf_counter()  # better for timing performance
    x.processImage()
    print(f"Run time {perf_counter() - start_time} seconds")

